# Specify read buffer size in NetCDF (Python or C)

Tags: python, c, buffer, benchmarking, netcdf

I would like to benchmark `NetCDF` `I/O` performance compared to reading a plain binary file in `Python` and `C`.

For reading the binary file, I have defined different buffer sizes to read. Here is the code of the read function in `Python`:

```
def parse_os_read(filename, buffersize):
    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    for loops in itertools.count():
        record = f.read(buffersize)
        if not record:
            break
    return loops
```

I can then call this function with different buffer sizes ranging from 64 KB to several 100 MB.

I would like to implement now a comparable sequential reading benchmark for `NetCDF`. However, I could not identify a read function, where I can set a pre-defined buffer size. I assume the `NetCDF` file should have a 1D array with random `floats` as a data structure.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to write code that dynamically allocates a buffer of the appropriate size and reads a file into it?

Comment: No. As the binary read example shows, it is just for the purpose of reading each part of a file. So, I want to read, for example and if it is possible, from the NetCDF file each time 64KB, throw it away, and then read the next 64 KB until the end of the file (see the variable record in the above code excerpt). If this is not feasible or is against the purpose of NetCDF, I am also open to other ideas to compare the read performance of NetCDF against a plain binary file.